# Implement Spring Security without user Role

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I want to implement Spring Security without user Role. I tried this:

I want to configure Spring Security to use database for Rest api requests. I tried this:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Import(value= {Application.class, ContextDatasource.class})
    @ComponentScan(basePackages= {"org.rest.api.server.*"})
    public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired 
        private RestAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    //      auth
    //      .inMemoryAuthentication()
    //      .withUser("test")
    //      .password(passwordEncoder().encode("testpwd"))
    //      .authorities("ROLE_USER");
            auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
            auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        }
        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
            authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
            return authenticationProvider;
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/securityNone")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        }
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
    public interface MerchantsService {

        public Merchants getCredentials(String login, String pwd) throws Exception;
    }
```

Service implementation

```
@Service
@Qualifier("merchantsService")
@Transactional
public class MerchantsServiceImpl implements MerchantsService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Merchants getCredentials(String login, String pwd) throws Exception {
        String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e where e.login = ? and e.pwd = ?";

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, login).setParameter(1, pwd);
        Merchants merchants = (Merchants) query.getSingleResult();

        return merchants;
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
    @Service
        public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

            @Autowired
            private MerchantsService merchantsService;

            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
 Merchants user = merchantsService.getCredentials(username, pwd);

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()){
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
}

        }
```

I have 2 issues:

1. How I can use Spring Security with user Role?
2. How I can authenticate requests with username and password. I see that `public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)` can accept only username. Is there other way to implement the code?

Answer (score 0):

As Spring Security is all about authentication and authorization. You want to do authentication by yourself and also you don't need the role. Then why so you are using Spring Security. Spring Security provides the best way to do the authentication and authorization for you, so should use it. As you already have the implementation of `UserDetailsService`. Spring Security itself doing the password verification using  configured `PasswordEncoder` bean.